# NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey deadlocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, deadlock

Today I encountered a rather confusing Problem:

When my app starts I'm downloading some things and after parsing the responses I write the data to the NSUserDefaults. 
Now this was working fine until I recently discovered that sometimes my entire UI freezes and wont unfreeze until I relaunch the app. When I hit pause programm execution in the debugger I get:

[image: Stacktrace]

The documentation says that NSUserDefaults is threadsafe and from what I can see no other threads are trying to access the user defaults...

Any Ideas on how to resolve/further debug the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

*Code that's causing the problem:*

This is called after I receive a response the webservice:

```
+ (void)updateWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *decodedData;

    if (data) {
        decodedData = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                            options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                             format:NULL
                                                              error:&error];
    }

    if (!error && decodedData) {
        [userDefaults setObject:decodedData forKey:kUserDataUserDefaultsKey];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? `NSUserDefaults` is thread-safe because  when `setValue: forKey:` is called, it locks the access to dictionary containing values.

Comment: Have you found the cause of this issue? I'm experiencing similar deadlocks when using NSUserDefaults concurrently.

Comment: I"m running into a similar problem, mine is device specific.  No problems on simulator and most other phones, but with iPhone 5s.  I'm thinking it is a timing issue.   If I can put a delay in somewhere to clean it up ?

Comment: Still happens time to time on iOS 11.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Updated with new code sample:

You should convert the decodedData into archived data in order to store it in NSUserDefaults:

```
if (!error && decodedData) {
    NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: decodedData]];
    [userDefaults setObject: archivedData forKey:kUserDataUserDefaultsKey];
}
```

And retrieve the data with this:

```
NSArray *storedData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kUserDataUserDefaultsKey]];
```

Comment: Thats interesting.. You think that's the reason for the lock?

Comment: @Subbu I'd say this is more of a 'kill it with fire' solution assuming the problem is caused by the passed data not conforming to NSCoding protocol.

Comment: @thattyson Thanks for your answer! However I hardly think that this would be causing a lock. After propertyListWithData:... returns he decodedData array contains just NSString objects which does conform to NSCoding...

Comment: Also its working most of the time. Just sometimes the thread seems to be deadlocked...

Comment: @DavidSilverfarmer Ah, I guess I read your question wrong; didn't realize it was only freezing some of the time.